# Access a host-server using OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, ping

I have the files to connect to a VPN (ca.crt, ...crt, ...key, ...ovpn). I have copied them to ...OpenVPN/config route and I have then proceed to start OpenVPN client in my Win10 successfully.

I am being assigned the IP 10.8.0.10: [ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv7Ln.png)

If I print my routes I can see how I can supposedly access to remote network ips (198.168.48.x, 192.168.49.x, etc): [print route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RitKc.png)
Being 10.8.0.5 the gateway.

But if I try to ping the remote gateway or the remote pcs (where I can find my server) I get timeouts: [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmPBT.png)

I assume the problem is that my pings are trying to get out of my network using the gateway of the first Ethernet adaptor, but I'm not sure what is happening or how can I solve it.

Note: Windows firewall is deactivated.

Comment: `I assume the problem is that my pings are trying to get out of my network using the gateway` - Don't assume, test that with traceroute.  Since this is Windows try `TRACERT.EXE remoteip`.

Comment: I get just "  *          *            *         timeout" in every instance

Comment: Is the firewall on the openvpn server also allowing your pings? BTW, why mask the final byte of the 192.168.48.* addresses, what danger do you see there?! Note that it's preferable to cut and paste the text into your question, images are a pain.